Why isn't the hasher recognized?
Submitted as bug#118230.
I want to use std::unordered_set::emplace, so write the following code:
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

struct S {
    struct Hasher_Cmper {
        using is_transparent = int;
        /* Hash */
        auto operator()(const auto& s) const noexcept {
            return std::hash<std::string>{}(std::string{s});
        }
        /* KeyEqual */
        bool operator()(const auto& a, const auto& b) const noexcept {
            return std::string{a} == std::string{b};
        }
    };
    std::unordered_set<std::string, Hasher_Cmper, Hasher_Cmper> set;
    void test() {
        this->set.emplace("123");
    }
};

int main() {}

However, the compiler g++-14.2.0 consistently complains:
static assertion failed: hash function must \
be invocable with an argument of key type:
    static_assert(
        __is_invocable<const _Hash&, const _Key&>{}, ...

Can't S::Hasher_Cmper{} be called by passing a std::string?

g++ sometimes works well when I use a single auto as operator()(Key)'s return type.  Anyway I'll report this to GCC and paste the bug number here later.

Only libstdc++ rejects it, not sure if it's a bug.

"123" is NOT a std::string (but a const char*). your code should be set.emplace(std::string{"123") or you should add overloads for const char*

@PepijnKramer Please consult cpppreference about std::unordered_set::emplace and Hash::is_transparent and KeyEqual::is_transparent

@shynur I never used is_transparent, so didn't know about its existence. Thanks for the link.

Changing auto to size_t allows compilation, which seems to be a bug in libstdc++.

@康桓瑋: You can post it as an answer.  And I will report this to GCC. :-)

Sidenote: The point of making transparent comparators / hashers is to not have to create real instances, but your Hasher_Cmper doesn't do that. You could use string_views instead. example

Catching up with C++14 features after reading the question, I have to say using is_transparent = int; causes a double and triple take because of the unexpected and unnecessary appearance of int.

@Jon I choose int because it consists of only 3 letters.

@shynur yes, and I also thought that you chose using over typedef for similar reason
